# Bootstrapped effect sizes

Tags: r, anova, fixed-effects-model, effect-size, generalized-eta-squared

I am working on a factorial design (3 factors) and want to use bootstrapped estimates of the effect size. I am unable to execute this with the boot function of R.

```
Model: Y ~ factor(A) * factor(B) * C
```

Here is the sample data and the code I am using (based on [this](https://sammancuso.com/2015/05/18/bootstrapped-anova-and-ancova-in-r/)), along with the error it generates.

```
ws <- data.frame(A = c(rep(0.02, 10), rep(0.4, 10), rep(0.8, 10)),
             B = c(rep(2, 10), rep(6, 10), rep(11, 10)),
             C = c(rep("a", 15), rep("b", 15)),
             Y = sample(x = 30:9000, size = 30, replace = TRUE))

es_boot <- function(formula, data, i) {
    data_resamp <- data[i,] # Resample rows
    model <- aov(formula, data = data_resamp)
    es <- lsr::etaSquared(model, type = 1)[, "eta.sq"] # Extract effect sizes
    return (as.vector(es))
}

esboot_run <- boot(statistic = es_boot,
                   formula = "Y ~ factor(A) * factor(B) * C", 
                   data = ws, 
                   R = 2000)

**Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: This is more of a software programming question and should be migrated to Stack Overflow where questions of this type are appropriate. Alternatively, you could post it on one of the many R user community sites or blogs.

Comment: Noted, will migrate and delete this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this here, since I don't see the migrated question on SO.

The problem is that `formula` needs to be changed to `as.formula(formula)` in the `aov` call.

Comment: Thank you, there is a 90 min limit before I could migrate! But now I don't need to migrate, I guess...